# Setting proxy on localhost in WebBrowser Control

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++, proxy, localhost, webbrowser-control

I am developing a hosted browser using IE Web Browser control. I have set SOCKS4 proxy settings in my browser. Now I am facing one problem. If my URL is "localhost:80" then it is not using proxy settings.

Is there any way I can apply proxy settings on localhost request?

Thanks